# How do I replace and update a string multiple times in Python?

Tags: string, python-2.7, replace

I'm working on a quiz program and need some help. I'm trying to replace words one at a time, but Python isn't saving the previously replaced string. Here is a mini example of what I mean:

```
replacedQuiz=""
easyQuiz = """
You can change a string variable to an integer by typing (__1__)
in front of the variable. It also works vice versa, you can change an 
integer
variable to a string by typing (__2__). This is important to remember before
you __3__ strings together, or else a TypeError will occur. While adding an
integer to a string, it is important to separate it using a __4__ (use the
symbol). \n"""

def replaceWord(replaced, quiz, numCount):
    if numCount == 1:
        replaced = quiz.replace("__1__", "int")
    if numCount == 2:
        replaced = replaced.replace("__2__", "str")
    if numCount == 3:
        replaced= replaced.replace("__3__", "concatenate")
    if numCount == 4:
        replaced= replaced.replace("__4__", ",")    
    print replaced

def easy():
    QCount=1
    print easyQuiz

    while QCount < 5:
        replaceWord(replacedQuiz, easyQuiz, QCount)
        QCount += 1

print easy()
```

I thought that by making a String called replacedQuiz, it would save the first replacement and then I could continue replacing the words inside the quiz and updating it. Please help! I don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: In your function, shouldn't `replacedQuiz` be `replaced`?

Comment: Yea sorry, I updated it to be a smaller version of what I had and missed that. I have tried that though and it still didn't work. (I edited it ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a slight mistake in the scope of your variable `replacedQuiz` (it'd certainly suggest that you check out some [explanation](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php) of this topic). Basically, you are replacing `replacedQuiz` by its new value only within your current function. Your other functions only have access to the global value you defined earlier. There are several ways to fix this (e.g. the `global` keyword) but the standard way would be to return the new `replacedQuiz` from your function.

To do so, add the following line to the end of your `replaceWord` function:

```
return replacedQuiz
```

This tells Python to use this value at the line it was called at. You can then define a new value for `replacedQuiz` *within* `easy` by just defining it as the returned value:

```
replacedQuiz = replaceWord(replacedQuiz, easyQuiz, QCount)
```

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for a few hours!

Comment: No problem, just glad it worked out. Hopefully it has taught you something ;), we all had to start somewhere. If you accept the answer, others won't see it come by as unsolved any more and they can help someone else :).